# java: package javax.persistance does not exist in springBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.scode</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Demo</name>
    <description>Demo projectŌ for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my pom.xml file. But when I run the project I have get error like `java: package javax.persistance does not exist`

I am a beginner and can someone help me to solve this issue

I have download javax.persistance jar and import. But it is not works

I try to add hiberate-entitymanager for pom.xml file. But it also not works

I tried to external import hibernate-jpa. It also not works

[image]

Comment: Did you try to refresh the dependencies?

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov yes

Comment: I think it's a dependency issue in the IDE. Could you please execute 'mvn clean install' and let me know if the project build passes?

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov It gives this error
```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/springboot/Demo/src/main/java/com/scode/Demo/entity/Department.java:[2,25] package javax.persistance does not exist
[ERROR]  
```

Comment: If I removed @Entity and import javax.persistence, then build it properly

Comment: Yes, because the issue is that can't find this Entity. I don't think you need from javax.persistence-api and hibernate-entitymanager as you use Spring-data-jpa. Can you try to remove them and see if you have the import option, not sure if there is some conflict as Spring-data-jps brings hibernate

Comment: it should be `javax.persistence` and not `javax.persistance` (note the e vs a)

Comment: Great, you find the issue. Always use IDE import and remove the dependencies that are not used and can bring such misleading

Answer (score 0):

In my case after I add this dependency to pom.xml, It worked

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

After I have build my project `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

use this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).